# jqm+backbone.Js+require.Js show loading message before page load

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I' m using Jquery mobile 1.1, I want to show the loading message before the page load
using backbone router. the mobile init code is

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
$.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg="loading";}
```

but the loading message is not shown.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual way is not going to help you because jQuery Mobile will show loader ONLY if page i loading into the DOM more then 10ms, even then it will hide when page is loaded into the DOM. Usually if page is complex this will be long before page is successfully show.

But you can manually show/hide it.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/qx7Yn/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function(){     
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $.mobile.loading('show');
        clearInterval(interval);
    },1);    
});

$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){  
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        //$.mobile.loading('hide');
        clearInterval(interval);
    },1);      
});
```

Basically all you want to do is show loader when page is about to be created and hide it during the pageshow event. In my case this line :

```
//$.mobile.loading('hide');
```

is commented because page is simple and it will load in a moment. Also dont forget to use this:

```
$.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
$.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = true;
$.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
```

Everything you need is in my jsFiddle example.

**EDIT :**

This example is compatible with jQuery Mobile 1.1.: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/qx7Yn/

Comment: thanks for the code.cool
The code works fine for simple pages
but I'm using backbone and works only for single page but not for other pages.
any suggestions?

Comment: First, can you check if page events are triggering on other pages or not at all? We need to find out is there a problem with page events or function for ajax loader.

Comment: the problem is that the loader goes off in first page and dont in other pages. if i press refresh button on next page then the loader goes off. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer @Gajotres,
but since i' m using jquery-mobile-1.1
i use

> ```
> $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function(){     
> var interval = setInterval(function(){
>     $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg('show');
>     clearInterval(interval);
> },1);     }); $(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){  
> var interval = setInterval(function(){
>     $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg('show');
>     clearInterval(interval);
> },1);       });
> ```

but the loading message doesnt goes off :(

Comment: If take a look, during the closing process you are trying to show it again, instead of hiding it. Show it with this line: $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true) and hide it with this: $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

Comment: I have created you an example compatible with jQM 1.1: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/qx7Yn/